# Ubunut 20.04 on x570/amd3700x is randomly not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, amd-ryzen, nvme

I am having a x570/amd3700x machine with Windows10 and ubuntu20.04 OSes. Randomly both windows and ubuntu are not booting. Even sometimes when I use ubuntu it abrubtly shutdowns.

Below mentioned is the behaviour when I face issue in booting.

1. "Asus Tuf Gaming" logo comes up.
2. "Press Del or F2" page comes up.
3. QLED on mobo stuck at Boot LED.
4. Then after few seconds no display on monitor. And CPU and Tower Fan spinning stops. But surprisingly my GSKill 16GB RAM's RGB continues glowing. Only after I switch off the UPS the RAM's RGB goes off. **This behaviour is weird**.

I am using Samsung 970 NVMe SSD 1 TB. I cleaned and reinserted the SSD stick. But even after that issue is not resolved.

`dmesg` shown an error related to NVMe which I shown below. My ubuntu installed on `nvme0n1p6` paritition.

```
$ dmesg | grep error -i
[    0.863188] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    3.861333] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.079071] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
```

```
$ dmesg | grep fail -i
[    4.079071] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    4.294173] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

I dont know whether the issue is in Ubuntu OS or Grub or NVMe SSD. Any suggestion to find out the problem will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance. My entire machine is just 1 year old.

Comment: Does Windows also boots from Grub?  If so, then it may be a problem with Grub, so you can try update or reinstall, else it may be hardware failure.

Comment: Yes. Windows also boots from Grub. And I updated grub from ubuntu using `sudo update-grub` and updated X570 BIOS firmware. Anything else can I try ?

Comment: Reinstall Grub.

Comment: Now powering on my system stucks at 3rd led (VGA LED) for max 2 second and power off immediately. I am using ASUS 1060i graphics card. I am going to test PSU, problem might be there.

Comment: Now it is not stucking at 3rd lead. It continues to stuck at 4th led (BOOT led).

Comment: I entered BIOS setting and changed boot order to a USB drive with ubuntu image. Even now it is not booting, it is getting stuck at Boot led for 5 to 7 secs and power goes off.